# Best way to create/generate XLIFF (or simply xml)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xliff

Just being curious, what would be the best practice to create/generate XLIFF(even simply xml) file (in my case from Excel data) in C# and .NET 4.5?
There are several option available but then I would like to know (preferably discuss) which one would be more preferable option in terms of efficiency.

- XmlDocument
- XmlWriter & XmlSerializer
- XDocument
- XmlTextWriter
- So on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to have the document in memory use `XmlWriter` ([and not XmlTextWriter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2011/10/08/the-world-has-moved-on-have-you-xml-apis-you-should-avoid-using.aspx)) if you want to be able to modify the document after loading use `XDocument` (Linq to Xml)

You may also want to take a look at the post I wrote some time ago comparing different Xml APIs: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2011/09/14/effective-xml-part-1-choose-the-right-api.aspx

Comment: Yes, after reading a bit, `XmlWriter` seems to be the better way. No, I don't have to modify document, simple process just convert Excel to XLIFF in a certain pre-defined xml structure, thanks

Comment: Updated the answer with some useful links.

Comment: [here it is](http://www.31a2ba2a-b718-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66.com/2010/02/xmldocument-versus-xdocument-versus.html), this is the one I found something with actual comparison or a proof.

Answer (score 2):

XmlWriter is probably the quickest, but this is like writing assembly when you could be writing in C#. I'd stay away in terms of readability.

I have no love of XmlTextWriter, in my opinion you may as well stick with XmlWriter.

XmlDocument has a lot of overhead. It's just too slow for almost anything you may want to do.

I don't trust or like XmlSerializer. It always seems to fragile to me. A future developer can unwittingly screw things up just by changing a few class definitions.

XDocument is pretty damn good. I've tried to do speed tests of XmlReader/XmlWriter against XDocument before and the two are often so close in performance, that I'd almost recommend XDocument in all cases. I say almost because XmlReader/XmlWriter is still the technically fastest way to read/write xml I've found.

Comment: I wrote a post on XmlWriter vs. XmlTextWriter some time ago http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2011/10/08/the-world-has-moved-on-have-you-xml-apis-you-should-avoid-using.aspx. You should use XmlWriter and not XmlTextWriter.